# Implementation of attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

Excuse me for the noob question.Please explain me outputs of the below ruby programme for implementing attr_accessor.

```
  class SimpleService

        attr_accessor :name

        def initialize(name)
          @name = name
        end

        def process
          if false # some condition met
            name = 'Akshay'
          end
          name
        end
      end
```

When I execute this class

```
      SimpleService.new('John Doe').process
      => nil
```

Why is the result nil?

when I use self explicitly to name

```
    def process
        if false # some condition met
          self.name = 'Akshay'
        end
        name
      end
```

Now the output is

```
    SimpleService.new('John Doe').process
    => "John Doe"
```

why is the result now "John Doe"?

I am a beginner in ruby.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag I disagree this is a duplicate. This question is more about why using the explicit receiver under `if false` changes the behavior of the returned value, that _does not require an exlicit receiver_ by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is when you call `name =` you implicitly declare new local variable. Try this:

```
def process
  name = 'Akshay'
  puts local_variables.inspect
end
```

Why is it that way is a complicated question, discussed many times there and here. The setter always requires in explicit receiver. Period.

Once you have the line `name = 'Akshay'` inside a method, you *introduce a new local variable* and this method’s scope gets extended with new local variable `name`, despite how is was declared. It’s basically done by *ruby parser*.

And local variables take precedence over instance methods. That is why what is returned in the last line is a local variable. That was apparently not set, due to falsey condition above. Hence `nil`.